# Sorting when comparisons cost no time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I want to sort an array, A, under this cost model:

1. For any value x, an assignment of the form A[i] = x has a cost of 1. Furthmore, A[i] = A[j] has a cost of 1.
2. Other operations, such as comparing and assignments of the for x = A[i] (where x is not a location in the array) has a cost of 0.

Questions:

1. Give a lower bound on the worst-case time required to sort the array A. Your answer should be an exact expression in terms of n and not use asymptotic notation.
2. Describe a sorting algorithm that uses O(n) space. The runtime should exactly match the lower bound given in 1 (exactly, not asymptotically).
3. Describe an in-place sorting algorithm that is optimal to this cost model. The runtime should exactly match the bound given in 1 (exactly, not asymptotically).

My attempts:

1. n. This is because, in the worst case, n elements of the array are in an index they are not supposed to be in. Therefore it will take n assignments to get the array in a sorted order.
2. My algorithm in psudo code:

   ```
   def weird_sort(A):
       B = an array the same size of A
       C = an array of bools (default True) the same size of A
       for i in range(0, A.size):
           min = first index in c that is True
           for j in range(0, A.size):
               if (A[j] < A[min]) and (C[j]):
                   min = j
           B[i] = A[min]
           C[i] = False
       A = B
   ```

I believe this takes exactly n time to run since the only time we are assigning anything into A is in the last line, where we copy the contents of B into A.

3. No idea where to start. It appears to me that in order to keep everything in place we have to swap things in array A, but I can't figure out how to go about how to sort an array with n/2 swaps. Can someone get me moving in the right direction? Can you also scrutinize my answer for 1 and 2?

Comment: This might be a better question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This sounds like the exact case that cycle sort was invented for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I consider inplace to allow `O(1)` additional variables since otherwise I don't think it's possible

First lets solve subproblem: Given `i`, find the number which should be on `i`-th position. It's possible to do using bruteforce since comparing is free.

Now copy 1st element(to additional variable), find smallest element and put it in position 1. Now this element was in position `i`. Let's find element which should be on position `i` and copy it here (suppose it was on position `j`), now find element which belongs to position `j`, etc. Eventually we found element we initially copied, put it back. So, we set `k` variables to their places using `k` assignments (in a cycle structure). 
Now do the same for all other elements. You can't remember for each variable whether you put in its place, but you can check if it is on its place for free.

If there are equal elements in A this should be done more carefully but it should still work

Answer (score 0):

Although when talking about *efficient sorting* algorithms, we usually tend to talk about quicksort, this kind of algorithms are optimized the number of comparisons.

Other algorithms, however, try to optimize the number of memory accesses instead (as in your case). Some of them are called cache-oblivious algorithms (don't make assumptions on the specific memory hierarchy parameters) and cache-aware (they are tuned for a specific memory hierarchy). You can find multiple algorithms of this kind, so you might be interested in giving them a look.

As an example, [Harald Prokop's PhD thesis](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/Prokop99.pdf) talks about cache-oblivious algorithms, and proposes the distribution sort, which partially sorts the data in sub groups that potentially fit in the lower partitions of the memory hierarchy.

> Distribution sort uses `O(n ln(n))` work and incurs `O(1+ (L/n)*(1+logz(n))` cache misses to sort *n* elements.

where *L* is size of a cache bank and *z* the size of the cache itself. The performance model only assumes that there is only a single cache level, although it adapts to all the cache levels thanks to the oblivious property.

The fundamental concept is that the assignment cost changes depending on where an element is placed in the memory hierarchy.